# Blank Second Activity page on text input

Tags: android, setcontentview

I am new here, and new to Android Programming as well. So any help on this will be greatly appreciated.

I am running an Android App(basically the example given in developer.android.com).The idea of the app is to let the user enter a message in the 1st screen, and display the message in the second screen.

The problem i have is when i use following code in "OnCreate" in "DisplayMessageActivity.java" then my application works fine and show the text on the second screen perfectly.

```
public class DisplayMessageActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setTextSize(40);
    textView.setText(message);

    setContentView(textView);
}
```

But when i use ,

```
setContentView(J.layout.activity_display_message);
```

instead of

```
setContentView(textView);
```

then it shows nothing just a blank second screen.

The code of "activity_display_message.xml" is as follows,

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".DisplayMessageActivity" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     />
</LinearLayout>
```

So my question is that why contentview ,referring "active_display_message.xml, dosen't working and which is a better way to display text,here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok , here is what you are doing

```
TextView textView = new TextView(this);
```

This means you're creating the TextView dynamically. You don't need to do this when you have `TextView` in `xml` file, unless you need. For your purpose here, you don't need to create `TextView` dynamically.

What you should do is to use the `TextView` you have created in `xml` file. You can access any control (TextView/EditText) that you have defined in `xml` by their `id` in java file using `findViewById(R.id.control_id)`, and id will be unique.

So first assign an id for your TextView

```
    android:id="@+id/tv_1"  // assigning id
```

Your layout file should look like this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation = "vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     />
</LinearLayout>
```

Then in your activity, do the following

```
public class DisplayMessageActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.your_xml);    // set the view that you want to display

Intent intent = getIntent();
String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_1)   // make sure the id is correct
myTextView.setText(message);   // set the value 
myTextView.setTextSize(40);    // you can dynamically modify the text size
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I'm also new to Android, so this might be unknown to me, but in everything I've read thus far I've never seen `J.layout`, but rather `R.layout`.

Comment: Sorry ! My bad ! its "R.layout"

Answer (score 0):

To use `TextView` in the layout, first you need to set the `android:id` attribute for `TextView` in your `active_display_message.xml` layout. Then in the activity, call it using `findViewById` method. For example:

in your layout:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_view_id"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
```

Then in your activity you need to call it:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view_id)
```